# Scatter plot of categorical data from multiple data frame columns

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, seaborn

I have a DataFrame `df` like this:

```
   name         Int1        Int2         Int3
0     foob -2.534519e-05 -1.156744e-04 -1.410195e-04
1     arz  2.907239e-04  3.502863e-04  6.410102e-04
2     foo2 -2.140769e-04  4.214626e-04  2.073857e-04
3     bar  3.366116e-03 -6.125303e-04  2.753586e-03
4     rnd -5.014413e-05 -6.740579e-06 -5.688471e-05
5     baz  3.334906e-04 -7.846232e-05  2.550283e-04
6     rnd2 -6.111069e-04  2.194443e-03  1.583336e-03
7     tet  3.184057e-04  2.208398e-04  5.392455e-04
```

The df should be plotted as a scatter plot depicting three data points (Int1, Int2, Int3) per name.

Currently, I am using **seaborn**'s `stripplot` function, which works fine if I assign a plot of each single column (e.g. x=name, y=Int1) to the same axis of a figure:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
seaborn.stripplot(df.name, df.Int1, ax=ax, c='red')
seaborn.stripplot(df.name, df.Int2, ax=ax, c='blue')
```

However, I want to plot this in a better way for the main reason of having a proper legend and better customization. The solution can also be **pandas** based.

Comment: I take it from your example that you want the `name` to appear on the horizontal axis, and above each one should be three points representing the three values from the row with that name? Do you want the points in each column to be the same color? If not, do you want a consistent color scheme that uses a single color for `Int1`, a different color for `Int2`, and another color for `Int3`?

Comment: @DavidZ Fully correct. The color scheme should be consistent among a single column (Int1) and different between each column (Int1 vs Int2 vs Int3). E.g. red, green, and blue for Int1, Int2, and Int3, respectively. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution. Actually quite simple:

```
df_melt=pd.melt(df,id_vars=['name'], var_name='intensities', value_name='values')
sns.stripplot(x="name", y="values", data=df_melt, hue='intensities')
```

This takes the original `df` and with the help of **pandas** `melt` function, produces a new df containing a single `intensities` column with one row for each of the `Int1`, `Int2`, and `Int3` values per name.
The second line uses **seaborn**'s `stripplot` to plot `df_melt` colored by the respective column `Int1`, `Int2`, and `Int3`